# Video source queuing function skips array element unintentionally

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple queue system that plays videos turn by turn. The video source is stored inside an array. The below code has a function that gets the first index element from the array plays that video, then removes that item from the array. It repeats the same method again and again until no elements are found inside the array.

It plays the first video as intended, but then skips the second video (array element) and plays the third. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

```js
myArr = ["http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4", "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4", "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"]

function test() {
  $('#player').attr('src', myArr[0])

  $("#player").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
    myArr = myArr.slice(1)

    var onEnd = setInterval(() => {
      $("#player").on("timeupdate", function() {
        var cTime = this.currentTime;
        var dur = this.duration;
        //console.log(cTime, dur)

        //check if video finished playing
        if (cTime == dur) {
          console.log('video Ended')
          if (myArr.length != 0) {
            clearInterval(onEnd)
            test()
          } else {
            clearInterval(onEnd)
            console.log('all videos played')
          }
        }
      });
    }, 500)
  })
}

test()
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="player" muted autoplay></video>
```

Comment: You are adding event listeners inside an interval, resulting in the possibility of multiple instances of `test()` functions running at once (each removing 1 from the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that not all videos were played yet, you call the `test` function again. But this function sets an event listener for `loadedmetadata`, and that listener advances the array by one. By calling `test` multiple times, you are setting multiple event listeners for the `loadedmetadata` event, *each* of which will fire and advance the array. You need to restructure your code such that the listener is only attached once.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Thanks, I will accept the answer when it allows me.